# Flutter - set result to return when the user navigates back

Tags: flutter

When calling `Navigator.pop()` a result can be passed to the previous screen. Is there a way to set the result so that if the user navigates back on their own the result is still returned to the previous page?

I could pass an object to the second page and then modify it so that the first page can check it when the second page returns, but I'd rather use the result returned from the Navigator as it's more readable.

Overriding the back button's tap detector as I've seen suggested elsewhere is not an acceptable solution because the user may navigate back in some other way such as swiping or pressing the Android back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass data between screens both ways.
While popping back, send the `data` you wish to send like this from the second screen

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // The Nope button returns "data" as the result.
    Navigator.pop(context, 'data');
  },
  child: Text('Nope!'),
);
```

And catch the result in the your first screen like this

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
  );
```

[source](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

For the other concern where the user is able to go back to the previous screen by pressing the back button, you can wrap your second screen with `WillPopScope` widget and provide the `onWillPop` callback. This will override the popping of the second screen and execute the callback where you can define the value you wish to return from the second screen.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(), // or your widget
      onWillPop: () {
        return Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 0), () {
          return Navigator.pop(context, "return-data");
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sadly WillPopScope doesn't meet my requirements as onWillPop requires returning a bool. If I return true then tapping the back button navigates back twice. If I return false then back swiping on iOS gets disabled. This is the best answer I'll probably get though  and it may be useful for others so I'm going mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: If it helps, you could use `Platform.isAndroid` and `Platform.isIOS` to check for the platform you are on and execute an appropriate piece of code to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: iOS swipe disabled is my main issue. Does anybody get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, when navigating to `Screen B` from `Screen A`, make the `onTap()` function`asynchronous` and await the result from `Screen B`.

Check the code below: It works perfectly:

On `Screen A`, put this code:

```
 onTap: () async {
        // receive the data you are sending from screen B here
        final result = await Navigator.push( context);
       },
```

On `Screen B`, put this code:

```
onTap: (){
    // pass the data you want to use in screen A as the second paramter
     Navigator.pop(context,number);
      },
```

I hope this helps

Comment: How does it help if the user pops the navigator by pressing the back button?

Comment: It sends back any data you want to send back to where the user is coming from. @ Ashutosh Singh